# How to edit a record that results in a uniqueness violation and echo the change to child tables?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, triggers

PostgreSQL 11.1

How can "Editing" of a record be transmitted to dependent records?

Summary of my issue:

- The master table, disease, needs a unique constraint on the description column. This unique constraint is needed for foreign key ON UPDATE CASCADE to its children tables.
- To allow for a temporary violation of the unique constraint, it must be made deferrable.  *BUT A DEFERABLE CONSTRAINT CAN NOT BE USED IN A FOREIGN KEY*.

Here is the situation.

- The database has 100+ tables (and keeps on growing).
- Most all information has been normalized in that repeating groups of information  have been delegated to their own table.
- Following normalization, most tables are lists without duplication of records. Duplication of records within a table is not allowed.
- All tables have a unique ID assigned to each record (in addition to a unique constraint placed on the record information).
- Most tables are dependent on another table. The foreign keys reference the primary key of the table they are dependent on.
- Most unique constraints involve a foreign key (which in turn references the primary key of the parent table).

So, assume the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE phoenix.disease
(
    recid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('disease_recid_seq'::regclass),
    code text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT disease_pkey PRIMARY KEY (recid),
    CONSTRAINT disease_code_unique UNIQUE (code)

        DEFERRABLE,
    CONSTRAINT disease_description_unique UNIQUE (description)
,
    CONSTRAINT disease_description_check CHECK (description <> ''::text)
)

CREATE TABLE phoenix.dx
(
    recid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('dx_recid_seq'::regclass),
    disease_recid integer NOT NULL,
    patient_recid integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_dx_recid PRIMARY KEY (recid),
    CONSTRAINT dx_unique UNIQUE (tposted, patient_recid, disease_recid)
,
    CONSTRAINT dx_disease_recid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (disease_recid)
        REFERENCES phoenix.disease (recid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT dx_patients FOREIGN KEY (patient_recid)
        REFERENCES phoenix.patients (recid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

(Columns not involved in this question have been removed. :) )

There are many other children tables of disease with the same basic dependency on the disease table. Note that the primary key of the disease table is a foreign key to the dx table and that the dx table uses this foreign key in a unique constraint. Also note that the dx table is just one table of a long chain of table references. (That is the dx table also has its primary key referenced by other tables).

The problem: I wish to "edit" the contents of the parent disease record. By "edit", I mean:

- change the data in the description column.
- if the result of the change causes a duplication in the disease table, then one of the "duplicated" records will need to be deleted.

Herein lies my problem. There are many different tables that use the primary key of the disease table in their own unique constraint. If those tables ALSO have a foreign key reference to the duplicated record (in disease), then cascading the delete to those tables would be appropriate -- i.e., no duplication of records will occur.

However, if the child table does NOT have a reference to the "correct" record in the parent disease table, then simply deleting the record (by cascade) will result in loss of information.

```
Example:
Disease Table:
    record 1:  ID = 1    description = "ABC"
    record 2:  ID = 2    description = "DEF"

Dx Table:
    record 5:  ID = 5   refers to ID=1 of Disease Table.

Editing of record 1 in Disease table results in description becoming "DEF"
Disease Table:
    record 1:  ID = 1   "ABC" --> "DEF"
```

I have tried deferring the primary key of the disease table so as to allow the "correct" ID to be "cascaded" to the child tables. This causes the following errors:

- A foreign key can not be dependent on a deferred column. *"cannot use a deferrable unique constraint for referenced table "disease"*
- additionally, the parent table (disease) has no way of knowing ahead of time if its children already have a reference to the "correct" record so allowing deletion, or if the child needs to change its own column data to reflect the new "correct" id.

So, how can I allow a change in the parent table (disease) and notify the child tables to change their column values -- and delete within them selves should a duplicate record arise?

Lastly, I do not know today what future tables I will need. So I cannot "precode" into the parent table who its children are or will be.

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: You have a foreign key reference to a description string that can change? Then you are suffering from bad database design. The string should be in the database only once. What keeps you from deleting conflicting entries before you update the column?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  I hope nothing -- I'm about to try that and see how it works. Thanks.